# Как переносить третью кнопку вниз только на айфоне

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, button

Есть три бутстраповские кнопки ([codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/GDh0FNDe1r))
и хочется, чтобы на iphone-ах третья кнопка съезжала вниз, а на ipad-ах и выше все три кнопки были в линию, но чтобы условия дивов `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">` не срабатывали, а работали марджины/паддинги кнопок, - так как кнопки могут быть разной ширины.

Приходит в голову:

1. Сделать 2 блока `<div class="visible-xs">` и `<div class="hidden-xs">`, а в них сделать 2 блока с кнопками: в первом с `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">`, во 2ом без этих дивов. Но это надо определять кнопки дважды...
2. Использовать медиа-запросы и подключать класс только на iphone-ах, а на остальных девайсах этот класс не определять. Что-то вроде `<div class="pseudo-col-xs-6">`. Но есть ли в CSS возможность присвоить классу `.pseudo-col-xs-6` свойства другого класса `.col-xs-6`, чтобы `.pseudo-col-xs-6` обрабатывался при разбивке на колонки как `.col-xs-6`?

Или есть лучший способ?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Классы колонок Бутстрапа отличаются только шириной для разных размеров экрана. Чтобы отключить ширину колонки на большом экране, достаточно добавить такой медиа-запрос:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-xs-6, .col-sm-4 {
    width: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Чтобы не обрушивать остальную вёрстку, можно добавить класс, управляющий шириной колонок внутри конкретного ряда. Проверьте результат:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .disable-the-width .col-xs-6,
  .disable-the-width .col-sm-4 {
    width: auto !important;
  }
}

.btn-group {
/* overflow: hidden; */
/* display: block; */
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: right;
/* float: right; */
  border: 1px solid blue;  /* DEBUGGING  */
}
.editor_btn_group button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  /* border: 2px solid maroon;  DEBUGGING  */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
     -moz-border-radius: 12px;
          border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row disable-the-width">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right editor_btn_group">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:onSubmit(1);">Update&amp;Reopen</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript:onSubmit(0);">Update&amp;Listing</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-cancel-action" onclick="javascript:document.location='http://local-tb.com/admin/tour/index/page/1/filter_feature/F/filter_status/A'">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, что-то стало получаться. 
  Если я Вас правильно понял:

Делаю подключение разных css фвайлов в зависимости от устройтва:

Одна из 3х кнопок должна сдвигаться на строку ниже, если ширина меньше 768px. В остальных случаях все 3 кнопки в 1у строку.

Определение

```
.col-xs-6, .col-sm-4 { 
  width: auto !important; 
}
```

я вставил ТОЛЬКО В style_sm.css файл

Определение

```
 .disable-the-width .col-xs-6,
 .disable-the-width .col-sm-4 {
     width: auto !important;
     border: 1px solid green;
 }
```

я вставил в style_sm.css, style_md.css, style_lg.css файлы
НО НЕ ВСТАВЛЯЛ в style_xs.css

И сделал верстку :

```
            <div class="row disable-the-width">
                <div class=" btn-group pull-right editor_btn_group col-sm-offset-right-2" >
                    <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" >Register Operator</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-4">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-cancel-action" value="Cancel">Medium Button</button> {# style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 10px;"#}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-cancel-action" onclick="javascript:document.location='{{ base_url }}'"  value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, http://dev4.softreactor.com/register на разных девайсах. Вроде нормально.
Я оставил бордюры для наглядности. И как раз желтый бордюр я прописал для col-sm-4 и желтый бордюр виден только на iphone-ах.

На этом сайте есть еще несколько редакторов - просмотрел, вроде все нормально...